# Computing the floor of log₂(x) using only bitwise operators in C

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, logarithm

For homework, using C, I'm supposed to make a program that finds the log base 2 of a number greater than 0 using only the operators `! ~ & ^ | + << >>`. I know that I'm supposed to shift right a number of times, but I don't know how to keep track of the number of times without having any loops or `if`s. I've been stuck on this question for days, so any help is appreciated.

```
int ilog2(int x) {
    x = x | (x >> 1);
    x = x | (x >> 2);
    x = x | (x >> 4);
    x = x | (x >> 8);
    x = x | (x >> 16);
}
```

This is what I have so far. I pass the most significant bit to the end.

Comment: Show what you have done.

Comment: The easiest solution is to return the position of the first non-zero bit.

Comment: Yet another one of these "bitwise" questions that allows `+`...

Comment: Can you use recursion and a ternary?

Comment: @Oli There's `10` kinds of people in this world...

Comment: No, I can only use the given operators. No loops, no ifs (all kinds of ifs), no recursion.

Comment: @abelenky: he said "floor".

Comment: http://aggregate.org/MAGIC/#Log2%20of%20an%20Integer

Comment: I thought I was precise when I said "floor"... If it came to 3.8, it would return 3.

Comment: Do you know what the largest possible value of the number is?

Comment: The link above will give you floor(log2(x)), where x is a 32-bit integer. Nothing too fancy about the answer though, simply shifting by 1, by 2, by 4, by 8 and by 16, and summing up the results.

Comment: @barakmanos That seems like the answer.

Comment: Yeah, well... if OP had mentioned it was a 32-bit integer to begin with, then he/she would have had the answer by now... BTW, the real neat stuff in that website is at http://aggregate.org/MAGIC/#Bit%20Reversal and http://aggregate.org/MAGIC/#Population%20Count%20%28Ones%20Count%29 (if you consider that kinda stuff neat of course)...

Comment: It works now, I'll post the working code. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Can I get some points for that?

Comment: If I could upvote, I would. Sadly, I don't have the reputation to upvote yet. You have my eternal gratitude, which is something I can give you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This gets the floor of logbase2 of a number.

```
int ilog2(int x) {

    int i, j, k, l, m;
    x = x | (x >> 1);
    x = x | (x >> 2);
    x = x | (x >> 4);
    x = x | (x >> 8);
    x = x | (x >> 16);

    // i = 0x55555555 
    i = 0x55 | (0x55 << 8); 
    i = i | (i << 16);

    // j = 0x33333333 
    j = 0x33 | (0x33 << 8);
    j = j | (j << 16);

    // k = 0x0f0f0f0f 
    k = 0x0f | (0x0f << 8);
    k = k | (k << 16);

    // l = 0x00ff00ff 
    l = 0xff | (0xff << 16);

    // m = 0x0000ffff 
    m = 0xff | (0xff << 8);

    x = (x & i) + ((x >> 1) & i);
    x = (x & j) + ((x >> 2) & j);
    x = (x & k) + ((x >> 4) & k);
    x = (x & l) + ((x >> 8) & l);
    x = (x & m) + ((x >> 16) & m);
    x = x + ~0;
    return x; 
}
```

Comment: This might be log10(x) or ln(x) but certainly not log2 (x).

Comment: @kuroineko: Why do you say that?

Comment: This answer is clever, I like it.  I don't see what the point of `m = 0xff | (0xff << 8);` is though… why not just `m = 0xffff`?

Comment: @DietrichEpp Sorry, the OP did modify the question while I was answering it, and I wondered why this code was so complicated. Usually it is used to compute the log in a different base, that's what I meant.

Answer (score 5):

Assumes a 32-bit `unsigned int` :

```
unsigned int ulog2 (unsigned int u)
{
    unsigned int s, t;

    t = (u > 0xffff) << 4; u >>= t;
    s = (u > 0xff  ) << 3; u >>= s, t |= s;
    s = (u > 0xf   ) << 2; u >>= s, t |= s;
    s = (u > 0x3   ) << 1; u >>= s, t |= s;

    return (t | (u >> 1));
}
```

---

Since I assumed `>`, I thought I'd find a way to get rid of it.

`(u > 0xffff)` is equivalent to: `((u >> 16) != 0)`. If subtract borrows:
`((u >> 16) - 1)` will set the msb, iff `(u <= 0xffff)`. Replace `-1` with `+(~0)` (allowed).

So the condition: `(u > 0xffff)` is replaced with: `(~((u >> 16) + ~0U)) >> 31`

---

```
unsigned int ulog2 (unsigned int u)
{
    unsigned int r = 0, t;

    t = ((~((u >> 16) + ~0U)) >> 27) & 0x10;
    r |= t, u >>= t;
    t = ((~((u >>  8) + ~0U)) >> 28) &  0x8;
    r |= t, u >>= t;
    t = ((~((u >>  4) + ~0U)) >> 29) &  0x4;
    r |= t, u >>= t;
    t = ((~((u >>  2) + ~0U)) >> 30) &  0x2;
    r |= t, u >>= t;

    return (r | (u >> 1));
}
```

Comment: The `>` operator is much like subtraction; doesn't seem to be allowed.

Answer (score 2):

Your result is simply the rank of the highest non-null bit.

```
int log2_floor (int x)
{
    int res = -1;
    while (x) { res++ ; x = x >> 1; }
    return res;
}
```

One possible solution is to take this method:

It is based on the additivity of logarithms:
**log<sub>2</sub>(2<sup>n</sup>x) = log<sub>2</sub>(x) + n**

Let **x<sub>0</sub>** be a number of **2n** bits (for instance, n=16 for 32 bits).

if **x<sub>0</sub> > 2<sup>n</sup>**, we can define **x<sub>1</sub>** so that 
**x<sub>0</sub> = 2<sup>n</sup>x<sub>1</sub>**
and we can say that
**E(log<sub>2</sub>(x<sub>0</sub>)) = n + E(log<sub>2</sub>(x<sub>1</sub>))**
We can compute 
**x<sub>1</sub>**
with a binary shift:
**x<sub>1</sub> = x<sub>0</sub> >> n**

Otherwise we can simply set **X<sub>1</sub> = X<sub>0</sub>**

We are now facing the same problem with the remaining upper or lower half of **x<sub>0</sub>**

By splitting x in half at each step, we can eventually compute **E(log<sub>2</sub>(x))**:

```
int log2_floor (unsigned x)
{
    #define MSB_HIGHER_THAN(n) (x &(~((1<<n)-1)))
    int res = 0;
    if MSB_HIGHER_THAN(16) {res+= 16; $x >>= 16;}
    if MSB_HIGHER_THAN( 8) {res+=  8; $x >>=  8;}
    if MSB_HIGHER_THAN( 4) {res+=  4; $x >>=  4;}
    if MSB_HIGHER_THAN( 2) {res+=  2; $x >>=  2;}
    if MSB_HIGHER_THAN( 1) {res+=  1;}
    return res;
}
```

Since your sadistic teacher said you can't use loops, we can hack our way around by computing a value that will be n in case of positive test and 0 otherwise, thus having no effect on addition or shift:

```
#define N_IF_MSB_HIGHER_THAN_N_OR_ELSE_0(n) (((-(x>>n))>>n)&n)
```

If the `-` operator is also forbidden by your psychopatic teacher (which is stupid since processors are able to handle 2's complements just as well as bitwise operations), you can use `-x = ~x+1` in the above formula

```
#define N_IF_MSB_HIGHER_THAN_N_OR_ELSE_0_WITH_NO_MINUS(n) (((~(x>>n)+1)>>n)&n)
```

that we will shorten to NIMHTNOE0WNM for readability.

Also we will use `|` instead of `+` since we know they will be no carry.

Here the example is for 32 bits integers, but you could make it work on 64, 128, 256, 512 or 1024 bits integers if you managed to find a language that supports that big an integer value.

```
int log2_floor (unsigned x)
{
    #define NIMHTNOE0WNM(n) (((~(x>>n)+1)>>n)&n)

    int res, n;

    n = NIMHTNOE0WNM(16); res  = n; x >>= n;
    n = NIMHTNOE0WNM( 8); res |= n; x >>= n;
    n = NIMHTNOE0WNM( 4); res |= n; x >>= n;
    n = NIMHTNOE0WNM( 2); res |= n; x >>= n;
    n = NIMHTNOE0WNM( 1); res |= n;
    return res;
}
```

Ah, but maybe you were forbidden to use `#define` too?
In that case, I cannot do much more for you, except advise you to flog your teacher to death with an old edition of the K&R.

This leads to useless, obfuscated code that gives off a strong smell of unwashed 70's hackers.

Most if not all processors implement specific "count leading zeroes" instructions (for instance, `clz` on ARM, `bsr` on x86 or `cntlz` on PowerPC) that can do the trick without all this fuss .

Comment: Ok sorry, I did not read the question carefully enough. Thanks for the rain of downvotes, BTW. Hackers are still very alive and kicking, it seems.

Answer (score 2):

If you're allowed to use `&` then can you use `&&`? With that you can do conditionals without the need of `if`

```
if (cond)
    doSomething();
```

can be done with

```
cond && doSomething();
```

Otherwise if you want to assign value conditionally like `value = cond ? a : b;` then you may do it with `&`

```
mask = -(cond != 0); // assuming int is a 2's complement 32-bit type
// or mask = (cond != 0) << 31) >> 31;
value = (mask & a) | (~mask & b);
```

---

There are many other ways in the [bithacks page](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerLog):

```
int v; // 32-bit integer to find the log base 2 of
int r; // result of log_2(v) goes here
union { unsigned int u[2]; double d; } t; // temp

t.u[__FLOAT_WORD_ORDER==LITTLE_ENDIAN] = 0x43300000;
t.u[__FLOAT_WORD_ORDER!=LITTLE_ENDIAN] = v;
t.d -= 4503599627370496.0;
r = (t.u[__FLOAT_WORD_ORDER==LITTLE_ENDIAN] >> 20) - 0x3FF;
```

or

```
unsigned int v;          // 32-bit value to find the log2 of 
register unsigned int r; // result of log2(v) will go here
register unsigned int shift;

r =     (v > 0xFFFF) << 4; v >>= r;
shift = (v > 0xFF  ) << 3; v >>= shift; r |= shift;
shift = (v > 0xF   ) << 2; v >>= shift; r |= shift;
shift = (v > 0x3   ) << 1; v >>= shift; r |= shift;
                                        r |= (v >> 1);
```

another way

```
uint32_t v; // find the log base 2 of 32-bit v
int r;      // result goes here

static const int MultiplyDeBruijnBitPosition[32] = 
{
  0, 9, 1, 10, 13, 21, 2, 29, 11, 14, 16, 18, 22, 25, 3, 30,
  8, 12, 20, 28, 15, 17, 24, 7, 19, 27, 23, 6, 26, 5, 4, 31
};

v |= v >> 1; // first round down to one less than a power of 2 
v |= v >> 2;
v |= v >> 4;
v |= v >> 8;
v |= v >> 16;

r = MultiplyDeBruijnBitPosition[(uint32_t)(v * 0x07C4ACDDU) >> 27];
```

Answer (score 1):

The question is equal to "**find the highest bit of 1 of the binary number**"

STEP 1: set the left of 1 all to 1
 like 0x07000000 to 0x07ffffff

```
x = x | (x >> 1);
x = x | (x >> 2);
x = x | (x >> 4);
x = x | (x >> 8);
x = x | (x >> 16); // number of ops = 10
```

STEP 2: returns count of number of 1's in word and minus 1

Reference: [Hamming weight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_weight)

```
// use bitCount
int m1 = 0x55; // 01010101...
m1 = (m1 << 8) + 0x55;
m1 = (m1 << 8) + 0x55;
m1 = (m1 << 8) + 0x55;
int m2 = 0x33; // 00110011...
m2 = (m2 << 8) + 0x33;
m2 = (m2 << 8) + 0x33;
m2 = (m2 << 8) + 0x33;
int m3 = 0x0f; // 00001111...
m3 = (m3 << 8) + 0x0f;
m3 = (m3 << 8) + 0x0f;
m3 = (m3 << 8) + 0x0f;

x = x + (~((x>>1) & m1) + 1); // x - ((x>>1) & m1)
x = (x & m2) + ((x >> 2) & m2);
x = (x + (x >> 4)) & m3;
// x = (x & m3) + ((x >> 4) & m3);

x += x>>8;
x += x>>16;

int bitCount =  x & 0x3f; // max 100,000(2) = 32(10)
// Number of ops: 35 + 10 = 45
return bitCount + ~0;
```

This is how I do. Thank you~

Comment: Good explanation of the same functions provided by the links of [barak manos](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1382251/barak-manos) on January 2014: [aggregate.org/MAGIC/#Log2 of an Integer](http://aggregate.org/MAGIC/#Log2%20of%20an%20Integer) and [aggregate.org/MAGIC/#Population Count (Ones Count)](http://aggregate.org/MAGIC/#Population%20Count%20%28Ones%20Count%29). Thanks also for the Wikipedia link.

Answer (score 0):

I also was assigned this problem for homework and I spent a significant amount of time thinking about it so I thought I'd share what I came up with. This works with integers on a 32 bit machine. !!x returns if x is zero or one.

```
int ilog2(int x) {

    int byte_count = 0;
    int y = 0;

    //Shift right 8
    y = x>>0x8;
    byte_count += ((!!y)<<3);

    //Shift right 16
    y = x>>0x10;
    byte_count += ((!!y)<<3);

    //Shift right 24 and mask to adjust for arithmetic shift
    y = (x>>0x18)&0xff;
    byte_count += ((!!y)<<3);


    x = (x>>byte_count) & 0xff;

    x = x>>1;
    byte_count += !!x;
    x = x>>1;
    byte_count += !!x;
    x = x>>1;
    byte_count += !!x;
    x = x>>1;
    byte_count += !!x;
    x = x>>1;
    byte_count += !!x;
    x = x>>1;
    byte_count += !!x;
    x = x>>1;
    byte_count += !!x;
    x = x>>1;            //8
    byte_count += !!x;


    return byte_count;

}
```