# How to calculate the log2 of integer in C as precisely as possible with bitwise operations

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, entropy

I need to calculate the entropy and due to the limitations of my system I need to use restricted C features (no loops, no floating point support) and I need as much precision as possible. From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21442088/computing-the-floor-of-log-2x-using-only-bitwise-operators-in-c/21443178) I figure out how to estimate the floor log2 of an integer using bitwise operations. Nevertheless, I need to increase the precision of the results. Since no floating point operations are allowed, is there any way to calculate `log2(x/y)` with `x < y` so that the result would be something like `log2(x/y)*10000`, aiming at getting the precision I need through arithmetic integer?

Comment: Maybe try `frexp` or [related functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/frexp)?

Comment: @KerrekSB I think that won't work because I have no way to store the fractional part for later processing (all I can use are `int` type variables). The whole idea is to transform `log2(x/y)` into `log2(x)-log2(y)` and then somehow insert the arithmetic integer into de logarith computation to obtain the otherwise fractional part as an arbitrary large integer.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I realize now that you want to compute the log2 of an integer. I was confused by your question title which says "log2 of float".

Comment: @KerrekSB my bad, I've edited the title accordingly

Comment: https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerLogObvious [Integer Log2 implemented using binary search](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/151312/34190), [What's the quickest way to compute log2 of an integer in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8970101/995714), [Fast computing of log2 for 64-bit integers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11376288/995714)

Comment: @phuclv, the lookup table version is going to faster https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerLogLookup (for that matter, so is https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerLogDeBruijn)

Comment: @nemequ I know. I just give the first solution so when people scroll down they can see all the possible ways

Comment: Searching the web for “fixed-point base-two logarithm” shows a number of relevant results, including [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4657468/fast-fixed-point-pow-log-exp-and-sqrt).

Comment: @chux: Your question about expressing the result is answered in the question, which gives `log2(x/y)*10000` as a sample form of acceptable result and asks about “something like” that, which indicates alternative formats are acceptable.

Comment: This previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32159300/compute-logarithmic-expression-without-floating-point-arithmetics-or-log/32163873#32163873) may be helpful, showing how to extract the binary logarithm one bit at a time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will base an algorithm on the formula

```
log2(x/y) = K*(-log(x/y));
```

where

```
 K        = -1.0/log(2.0); // you can precompute this constant before run-time
 a        = (y-x)/y;
-log(x/y) = a + a^2/2 + a^3/3 + a^4/4 + a^5/5 + ...
```

If you write the loop correctly—or, if you prefer, unroll the loop to code the same sequence of operations looplessly—then you can handle everything in integer operations:

```
(y^N*(1*2*3*4*5*...*N)) * (-log(x/y))
  = y^(N-1)*(2*3*4*5*...*N)*(y-x) + y^(N-2)*(1*3*4*5*...*N)*(y-x)^2 + ...
```

Of course, `^`, the power operator, binding tighter than `*`, is not a C operator, but you can implement that efficiently in the context of your (perhaps unrolled) loop as a running product.

The `N` is an integer large enough to afford desired precision but not so large that it overruns the number of bits you have available. If unsure, then try `N = 6` for instance. Regarding `K`, you might object that that is a floating-point number, but this is not a problem for you because you are going to precompute `K`, storing it as a ratio of integers.

**SAMPLE CODE**

This is a toy code but it works for small values of `x` and `y` such as 5 and 7, thus sufficing to prove the concept. In the toy code, larger values can silently overflow the default 64-bit registers. More work would be needed to make the code robust.

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
// Your program will not need the below headers, which are here
// included only for comparison and demonstration.
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

const size_t     N = 6;
const long long Ky = 1 << 10; // denominator of K
// Your code should define a precomputed value for Kx here.

int main(const int argc, const char *const *const argv)
{
    // Your program won't include the following library calls but this
    // does not matter.  You can instead precompute the value of Kx and
    // hard-code its value above with Ky.
    const long long Kx = lrintl((-1.0/log(2.0))*Ky); // numerator of K
    printf("K == %lld/%lld\n", Kx, Ky);

    if (argc != 3) exit(1);

    // Read x and y from the command line.
    const long long x0 = atoll(argv[1]);
    const long long y  = atoll(argv[2]);
    printf("x/y == %lld/%lld\n", x0, y);
    if (x0 <= 0 || y <= 0 || x0 > y) exit(1);

    // If 2*x <= y, then, to improve accuracy, double x repeatedly
    // until 2*x > y. Each doubling offsets the log2 by 1. The offset
    // is to be recovered later.
    long long               x = x0;
    int integral_part_of_log2 = 0;
    while (1) {
        const long long trial_x = x << 1;
        if (trial_x > y) break;
        x = trial_x;
        --integral_part_of_log2;
    }
    printf("integral_part_of_log2 == %d\n", integral_part_of_log2);

    // Calculate the denominator of -log(x/y).
    long long yy = 1;
    for (size_t j = N; j; --j) yy *= j*y;

    // Calculate the numerator of -log(x/y).
    long long xx = 0;
    {
        const long long y_minus_x = y - x;
        for (size_t i = N; i; --i) {
            long long term = 1;
            size_t j       = N;
            for (; j > i; --j) {
                term *= j*y;
            }
            term *= y_minus_x;
            --j;
            for (; j; --j) {
                term *= j*y_minus_x;
            }
            xx += term;
        }
    }

    // Convert log to log2.
    xx *= Kx;
    yy *= Ky;

    // Restore the aforementioned offset.
    for (; integral_part_of_log2; ++integral_part_of_log2) xx -= yy;

    printf("log2(%lld/%lld) == %lld/%lld\n", x0, y, xx, yy);
    printf("in floating point, this ratio of integers works out to %g\n",
      (1.0*xx)/(1.0*yy));
    printf("the CPU's floating-point unit computes the log2 to be  %g\n",
      log2((1.0*x0)/(1.0*y)));

    return 0;
}
```

Running this on my machine with command-line arguments of `5 7`, it outputs:

```
K == -1477/1024
x/y == 5/7
integral_part_of_log2 == 0
log2(5/7) == -42093223872/86740254720
in floating point, this ratio of integers works out to -0.485279
the CPU's floating-point unit computes the log2 to be  -0.485427
```

Accuracy would be substantially improved by `N = 12` and `Ky = 1 << 20`, but for that you need either thriftier code or more than 64 bits.

**THRIFTIER CODE**

Thriftier code, wanting more effort to write, might represent numerator and denominator in prime factors. For example, it might represent 500 as [2 0 3], meaning (2<sup>2</sup>)(3<sup>0</sup>)(5<sup>3</sup>).

Yet further improvements might occur to your imagination.

**AN ALTERNATE APPROACH**

For an alternate approach, though it might not meet your requirements precisely as you have stated them, @phuclv has given the suggestion I would be inclined to follow if your program were mine: work the problem in reverse, *guessing* a value `c/d` for the logarithm and then computing `2^(c/d)`, presumably via a Newton-Raphson iteration. Personally, I like the Newton-Raphson approach better. See sect. 4.8 [here](https://www.derivations.org/) (my original).

**MATHEMATICAL BACKGROUND**

Several sources including mine already linked explain the Taylor series underlying the first approach and the Newton-Raphson iteration of the second approach. The mathematics unfortunately is nontrivial, but there you have it. Good luck.

Comment: I've been trying to follow your recommendations but no success so far, I think I cannot fully understand your reasoning (e.g. to find `K`, `a`, and the `log(x/y)` series). Even without understanding it I tried to code it but the results are wrong. Could you please explain further and if possible provide a coding example?

Comment: Sure, why not? You have asked at a convenient moment, as it happens. I haven't written this kind of code in years, so the exercise serves to refresh old skills. Code posted. There you go.

Comment: @phuclv : for information, my answer has adopted your comment. Thanks.

Comment: this does exactly what I need. Thanks a lot! Once I figure out how to modify the code in order to satisfy larger number estimations I will post the update version. Thanks again!